# Is it possible to write a regex engine that uses grouping but does not do backtracking?

Tags: regex, denial-of-service

I am trying to understand [redos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS) in details and it is more or less clear why `(a|a)+x` fails on `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab` string, but I am curious if there is any example which does not use grouping? I read that the Thompson engine [is not vulnerable](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html) to this problem, because it does not do backtracking, but as far as I understand this means that it cannot have grouping either. Is it possible to do grouping without backtracking and the vulnerability that comes with it?

Comment: I do see a match [here](https://regex101.com/r/OyiMnh/1) when you say: "why `(a|a)+` fails on `aaaaaaaaaab` string".  But my regexp knowledge is limited ....

Comment: @Luuk Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Why would it match to begin with? Your string contains no literal `x`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It does not match, but it takes a few days for the engine to figure it out with 100% CPU usage...

Comment: @MadPhysicist Most engines are vulnerable to this and try out every possible combination of the `(a|a)+` pattern in the hope that maybe one of them will match the `b` character. There are other similar patterns too. Some of the engines are patched to protect against a few of them, but afaik the problem is not completely solved yet. For example the js regex engine is vulnerable to the upper pattern. I am not sure about Python and PHP regex engines.

Comment: RE2 is said to be a non-backtracking engine, and it supports groups.

Comment: Can you provide some programming example which takes " a few days for the engine to figure it out with 100% CPU usage" ?

Comment: @Luuk Try `/(a|a)+x/.test("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab")` with a javascript engine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer is Re2 according to Wiktor Stribiżew. It is possible to support grouping without backtracking. Re2 does not support stuff like backreferences, which is completely understandable, at least I doubt many engines prepare for patterns like this one `/(a)(a|\1)+b/.test("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaax")`. They write that lookaround is not fully supported either because of this. So these engines have limits, but they are good enough. Many people try to solve everything with a single pattern, which fuels this problem.